# Singleton in Multi Core processor

Tags: java, multithreading, singleton

An interviewer asked me this question and I got confused with this.

Question was : In your webapp where you implemented singleton DP, you are hosting it in a Quad Core processor. Which means 4 cores/threads. When a request comes from user, one thread will serve and when another request hits server, next thread will try to serve.

So in this scenario, how singleton objects will be shared between cores/threads.

Will they wait for the 1st one to complete? or anything else?

Comment: What is your answer? Do you think it's correct? If you don't, why?

Comment: First of all it depends on has your singleton some state or it is "stateless", if it's "stateless" then it's thread safe, if not than not.

Comment: Consider it is thread safe. But still one object per JVM. But 4 cores serving for HTTP Req/Res. What will happen if 2 http request arrived to JVM at same time?

Comment: It depends on how your Singleton is coded, which you do not tell us.

Comment: @Raedwald It was an interview question. And you need to consider that and answer the question please.

Comment: I don't know who downvoted for this. It is an interview question and I am here to learn what I missed in this. So why a downvote?

Answer (score 3):

Provided, the Singleton object is thread-safe, only one singleton object will be created per JVM. Also if the singleton object is shared by multiple threads, and each thread calls a particular method, each method invocation will be executed independently of other threads. Of course, there is a problem if the method is manipulating some shared property. In that case, you'll need to synchronize access to the singleton method.

Answer (score 1):

If the singleton implementation is not thread safe, then there is a possibility that two or more instances are created by the threads. You have to ensure it's thread safe when implementing the design pattern.

One of the best ways to do this is to use Initialization-on-demand holder idiom, since it abuses the ways JVM works when loading classes.

```
public class Something {
    private Something() {}

    private static class LazyHolder {
        private static final Something INSTANCE = new Something();
    }

    public static Something getInstance() {
        return LazyHolder.INSTANCE;
    }
}
```

A more general solution is to `synchronize` it yourself, but it's less efficient that the previous solution, since you have to use a double `if` condition.

```
public class ASingleton {

    private static ASingleton instance = null;
    private static Object mutex = new Object();

    private ASingleton() {
    }

    public static ASingleton getInstance() {
        if (instance == null) {
            synchronized (mutex) {
                if (instance == null)
                    instance = new ASingleton();
            }
        }
        return instance;
    }
}
```

Comment: This is a can of worms. There are several ways to correctly implement a Singleton. Joshua Bloch's ultimate solution is to use an enum for it (see http://www.journaldev.com/1377/java-singleton-design-pattern-best-practices-with-examples)

Answer (score 1):

The Singleton pattern means there is one instance *per JVM*. This means that the number of threads or processors is irrelevant - there will only be one instance in the Java Virtual Machine (i.e. the running process).

Of course, this does assume you follow one of the correct patterns for creating your singleton, such as assigning it to a static final class property so it gets loaded when the class is loaded by the class loader. If you initialise it badly you could potentially create more than one instance but this is still not affected by the number of cores/processors.

Comment: I think you missed the point. `Multiple cores/processors` means that a single JVM can run multiple threads, and multiple threads can access the singleton instance at the same time. What happens if you don't take care of concurrency?

Comment: exactly my point @BackSlash what will happen if a single jvm with 4 cores start serving singleton object.

Comment: @Rajkumar No. You are still missing the point. Imagine a single JVM instance, with a class, let's say class `A`. Class `A` contains a `main` method, which spawns 10 threads. All 10 threads want to access a singleton object, `B`. What will happen if all 10 threads access the same instance at the exact same time? Multiple cores = I can run multiple threads at the same time, which is **different from multiple JVMs**. A single JVM can run more threads, and if you don't take care of concurrency in your singleton, it might not work as expected.

Comment: @BackSlash now consider the scenario you mentioned, and consider that concurrency has been taken care of. So what next? Core A&B trying to access object B. what will happen?

Comment: Hmm, not really sure what's being asked then - what does "serving singleton object" mean? @BackSlash - you are of course right that the singleton would need to be thread safe, though again this is true irrespective of the number of cores/processors. A single core can still run multiple threads through a singleton concurrently with context switching.

Comment: @BarrySW19 My question is, if concurrency in thread has been handled and my class is thread safe. Now we are talking about one JVM and 4 cores/threads. If two HTTP requests come to server, and 2 threads picks them up, how will it access the singleton object?

Comment: Both threads will access the singleton simultaneously. Any static or class level properties will need to be coded as thread safe; obviously each thread will get its own copy of any variables defined locally in methods.

Answer (score 1):

Singletons are not thread safe by definition. If a singleton needs to be thread safe you will have to use synchronization when accessing it from different threads. Apart from that there is a difference between java threads and OS threads. A single-threaded Java application might benefit from a multithreaded OS (e.g. better performance) and a multi-threaded Java application can run on a single-threaded OS (e.g. by allocating CPU cycles to the different Threads in alternation).

Answer (score 1):

Both threads will execute the same code in parallel (which has nothing to do with whether the object is a singleton or not) and share the same memory (which is where the singleton comes in play).

Synchronization within the code may alter the way actual instructions execute controlling whether a thread is blocked or not at different times, but this is really a secondary issue and not what the interviewer is asking in my opinion.

Comment: This is the closest to answer in my opinion. Will try to simulate the scenario using tools and see what happens, if it is even possible

Answer (score 0):

> Will they wait for the 1st one to complete?

It is implementation dependent.

This singleton can only be called once at a time because of the synchronization mechanism:

```
public enum Singleton {
    INSTANCE;
    public synchronized int method() { return 1; }
}
```

This singleton can be called concurrently by as many threads as you want (the limitation is your hardware):

```
public enum Singleton {
    INSTANCE;
    public int method() { return 1; }
}
```